# Use ElasticSearch search URI into Python PyEs client

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I have the following working query, using CURL:

```
  curl -X GET 'http://myhost/myindex/_search?q=text:%7B1933%20TO%201949%7D'
```

which identifies all documents inside the index myindex which in the text field (string type) contains mentions of dates between 1933 and 1949. I would like to use this query programatically from Python, and in this sense I have the Python ElasticSearch client installed, Pyes:

```
  from elasticsearch import ElasticSearch
  from pyes import *
```

and then I would like to call

```
  es = ElasticSearch('myhost')
  totalDocs = es.search('myindex', body={'query':{'query_string':{'query': 'text:%7B1933%20TO%201949%7D'}},"size":0})['hits']['total']
```

but this syntax is not working. Also it is important that I look into the text field only for these date mentions. Are there any ways to use the initial query in Python? Many thanks!

Later edit: I have also tried it like this:

```
  totalDocs = es.search('myindex', 'text:%7B1933%20TO%201949%7D')['hits']['total']
```

It works, but it returns no documents at all.

Actually my question resumes to this question: [[ElasticSearch - specify range for a string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708184/elasticsearch-specify-range-for-a-string-field])

Comment: What result do you get? Is there an error message?

Comment: It doesn't crash but it doesn't return anything. I know for sure that there should be more than 100,000 documents that fulfill this condition in my index.

Comment: Would you please add your document's format?